# How to reduce WAR file size to deploy on Tomcat Server host?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-hosting, filesize

I have built a war file of my JSP project and I'm now ready to deploy it on my host. The plan I have has 288MB JVM Heap Size maximum capacity. Turns out the WAR file is 288MB... Obviously when trying to transfer the file into my host it returns an error message saying the file is too large for the destination folder (host). I was wondering is there a way to reduce the size of the WAR so I can deploy my project without having to pop the wallet out?

Comment: how is this related to the heap size?

Comment: @Stultuske: Well isnt the heap size the memory capacity? To my best knowledge, It is in reference to the amount of memory used by the objects, no?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? "destination folder" sounds like "disk space" (which indeed has nothing to do with heap size).

Comment: @Boobada: yes, it is the memory capacity. What you are describing, is the capacity of your hard drive, this has nothing to do with memory capacity. With a .war file of only a few kb, you can easily go over 288mb heap size. Just implement: List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(); while ( true ){ s.add(new String("new object")); }

Comment: @Thilo: I was even surprised to receive an error message when deploying as my plan has unlimited disk space... So I have created a remote connection with Web Disk to transfer the file from my computer on to tomcat/webapps/. When transferring the WAR this message returns: The file is too large for the destination folder...

Comment: Please post your complete war structure!!!

Comment: It must be related to the disk size, not heap size. If so, you have to take into account not only the .war file, but also disk usage by Tomcat once the application has been deployed - Tomcat will unpack the .war into an exploded directory, create temporary files, write logs, etc. Your application may need to write to disk as well.

Comment: the error appears whilst transferring the war file, so it is disk related.

Comment: @FranMontero: as soon as this is in the error message "file is too large for the destination folder" it is disk related.

Comment: just wanted to avoid heap subject here :P

Answer (score 0):

No really. The approach you are thinking is not well defined. It means that the size of your WAR file is because of:

1. JAR dependency (much heavier)
2. JSP
3. CSS
4. JS
5. Images (much heavier)
6. Required XML files

Now, if you look at above list, you can identify the heavy items. Now its up to you + project-scope to take decision to make it light.

I recommend you to do either way. You should increase the heap size of Servlet Container to resolve this issue. Because I am sure you are going to compromise with project dependency.

**Another Approach:**
Remove all unused dependency JAR from project, and see if it get reduced to expected size. Always use dependency, which can be used in project (eliminate all unused JAR files).

Let me know, if above solution/advice is not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..its an issue with disk space while extracting the war in tomcat. One thing can help out here is that we can get libraries dependencies (from lib) deployed seperately rather than carrying with war. So we can exclude these libs while preparing war/ear which will reduce the war size.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the constant files and variables on server in a directory and refer the path .

You can place libraries in tomcat's common directory (tomcat-dir/common/lib) and remove them from your dependencies in your war file (Managing libraries in tomcat).

Place static file on a cdn or another web application on your tomcat (that would require code modification though)